# Accessing void * in a struct in C

Tags: c, malloc

List.c

```
int const LIST_SIZE = 100;

typedef struct node {
    void *item;
} Node;

typedef struct list {
    Node *currentItem;
    Node *items[LIST_SIZE];

} LIST;
```

main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <printf.h>
#include "List.h"


LIST *ListCreate();

int main() {

    LIST *newList = ListCreate();

    Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));

    newList->currentItem = newNode;

    newNode->item = (int *)200;

    printf("%d", *((int *)newNode));

}

LIST *ListCreate() {
    LIST *newList = malloc(sizeof(LIST));
    return newList;
}
```

My question is:
In main.c, I use the printf statement to access the item in the newNode. According to my understanding the proper call should be:

```
printf("%d", *((int *)newNode->item));
```

However, I get a segmentation fault when using this. Could anyone please explain me why this doesn't work and the other one works?

Thanks.

Comment: `#include <printf.h>` is not a thing. Do you mean `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: @InternetAussie it was added by my IDE. Yes, it should have been the one you suggest. Thanks.

Comment: So is memory address 200 accessible? You are putting the value of 200 into the pointer `item` so when you dereference the pointer, you are attempting to print the int value at location 200.

Comment: @RichardChambers I see. But if the address 200 is being store in the item. How am I able to access it with *((int *)newNode)) ?

Comment: Sorry but your question doesn't make sense to me. What is it that you are actually trying to do?

Comment: @RichardChambers I mean: newNode is a struct, how can dereferencing it as an int * get me the value of *(newNode->item) in printf statement?

Comment: so is `item` to be a pointer with an address to an `int` or is it to be an `int` or a variable whose value is an `int`?

Comment: The question is really what is it that you want to do. Not what code to write but rather we need some description as to what algorithm are you attempting to write code for and what task you want to accomplish with the code. It sounds to me like you are trying to write code to do something and you do not fully understand what you want to accomplish nor how to write the code to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

`(int*)200` tells the compiler to take the number 200 and pretend it's the address of an `int`. However, it's not *actually* a valid address of an `int`, so you can't dereference it (i.e. you can't use `*(int*)newNode->item` to get the `int` at that address).

All you want to do is tell the compiler to take the "address" and treat it as a number again, which you can do using:

```
printf("%d", (int)newNode->item);
```

The `(int)` cast undoes the `(int*)` cast from before.

Side note: using `(int*)` here is slightly unusual; there's no reason to use it instead of `(void*)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're storing `200` (which isn't a pointer value) in the pointer variable, and then you deference the variable as a pointer even though it doesn't actually contains a pointer value.

---

General pattern for some type `type`:

```
Node* node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
node->item = malloc(sizeof(type));
*((type*)node->item) = ...;

type val = *((type*)node->item);

free(node->item);
free(node);
```

So, to store an `int`, it would be

```
Node* node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
node->item = malloc(sizeof(int));
*((int*)node->item) = 200;

printf("%d\n", *((int*)node->item));

free(node->item);
free(node);
```

Now, pointers can be used to store integers, so you could save an allocation in this particular case by using some trickery. This is a more advanced solution.

```
Node* node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
node->item = (void*)200;             // Store the number in a pointer variable.

printf("%d\n", (int)node->item);     // Treat the pointer variable as an `int`.

free(node);
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a slight change to the `main()` lets take a look at this application run using Visual Studio 2013 in debug mode.

The modified `main()` is as follows:

```
int main() {

    LIST *newList = ListCreate();

    Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));

    newList->currentItem = newNode;

    newNode->item = (int *)200;       // assign the value 200 to the pointer item

    printf("*((int *)newNode)  %d\n", *((int *)newNode));         // works
    printf("((int)newNode->item)  %d\n", ((int)newNode->item));   // works
    printf("*((int *)newNode->item)  %d\n", *((int *)newNode->item));  // access violation exception 

}
```

When this console application is run, the window displayed contains two lines of output:

```
*((int *)newNode)  200
((int)newNode->item)  200
```

In the debugger, when single stepping through the function `main()` an access violation exception is thrown on the indicated line. The actual text of the access violation is:

```
First-chance exception at 0x010E1BAF in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000C8.
Unhandled exception at 0x010E1BAF in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000C8.
```

The location being read, 0x000000C8, is the decimal number 200 and when an attempt is made to dereference the pointer `item` as an `int` pointer containing the value of 200, the memory location of 200 is not valid for this application running under Windows 10 in user mode.

`*((int *)newNode)` means to treat the value of the variable `newNode` as a pointer to an `int` and to then fetch the value at that address. This works because `newNode` contains an address this application can access.

`(int)newNode->item` means to treat the value of the variable `newNode->item` as an `int` and to fetch the value of that variable. The variable is not treated as a pointer but as a variable containing an `int`.

`*((int *)newNode->item)` means to to treat the value of the variable `newNode->item` as a pointer to an `int` and to then fetch the value at that address. This doesn't work because the value of the variable `newNode->item`, a value of 200, is not an address this application can access so an access exception is thrown when the attempt is made.

Answer (score -2):

> According to my understanding the proper call should be:

```
printf("%d", *((int *)newNode->item));
```

That is true only from a syntactic point of view. But it is wrong because you are not using pointers correctly.

```
newNode->item = (int *)200;
```

Not sure what you were expecting that line to do. Casting 200 to an `int*` does not give you a valid pointer.

```
*((int *)newNode->item
```

only dereferences the value `200` pretending to be a valid pointer. This causes undefined behavior.

You can use:

```
// Allocate memory for newNode->item
newNode->item = malloc(sizeof(int));

// Set the value
*((int *)newNode->item) = 200;

// Print the value
printf("%d", *((int *)newNode->item));
```

---

Unless you wish to store other kinds of object in a `node`, I suggest using:

```
typedef struct node {
    int item;
} Node;
```

and then your code can be a little bit simpler.

```
// Set the value
*newNode->item = 200;

// Print the value
printf("%d", newNode->item);
```

Comment: with hardware and an OS that allows it, 200 may be a perfectly valid pointer. An example would be a CPU that has special purpose registers at that location for communicating with other devices.

Comment: @RichardChambers, Just because 200 may be a perfectly valid pointer on some hardware does not make use of `(int*)200` a recommended way to write a program. The OP obviously is not using such a platform.